# How to add space in front of string in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the following string which is rendered, but I want the top string to move a bit to the left, i.e be centred on top of the line below it. How can I add space in front of the message to do so?

[image]

I have tried adding an array of space but its not working:

```
     const {totalMinutes} = this.state
     this.setState({
      message: new Array(6).join('  ') + "Your order is in line\n\n" + " Please wait " + totalMinutes + " minutes for more info"
     });
```

It's being rendered as follows:

```
                <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                  
                    <p
                      style={{ alignContent: "center", marginTop: "10px", color:"blue", whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}
                    >
                      {message}
                    </p>
                </div>
```

Comment: render it inside a div and then use flexbox or `text-align: center` to it

Comment: If always want the space, try using [text-indent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

Comment: Do you want ***all*** of the text centered? Or only the "Your order is in line" string/line specifically? What have you already tried on your own? How is `this.state.message` being rendered?

Comment: I've added the code to how its being rendered currently. @DrewReese I only want the "Your order is in line"  to be centred on top of the current one, because I have to do it in one state message

Comment: You'll need to split up the rendering of that text then, so you can center-justify the first line and left-justify the second line. The text also seems like it doesn't need to be stored in state either, just render it and render the `totalMinutes` state value into it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a requirement that I need to store it in the state. Thanks for your help though @DrewReese

Answer (score -1):

Try to add style property `alignText: center` for `<p>` tag